# Some help with a differentiation of vector components with respect to themselves

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Lets say that we have a vector with 3 components $n_1, n_2, n_3$, each of which depends on 3 coordinates $x_1, x_2, x_3$:

$$
\textbf{n}=(n_1(x_1,x_2,x_3), n_2(x_1, x_2, x_3), n_3(x_1, x_2, x_3))
$$

By comma, let's symbolize differentiation with respect to the index that follows, i.e., $$n_{1,1}=\partial{n_{1}(x_1,x_2,x_3)}/\partial{x_1}$$

What is the result for the following:
$$\partial{n_{1,2}}/\partial{n_{2,3}}$$

Best regards, and a big thanks for reading and replying!

Edit: Consider the functions of $n_1, n_2, n_3$ to be differentiable n-times (e.g. trigonometric) to avoid constants/zeros.

Comment: are you sure you want to ask this. this is meaningless. for example both ${n_{1,2}}$ and ${n_{2,3}}$ could be constants. since they are functions not variables, they cud as well be ... 

such doubts are bound to occur when you are starting ... good question though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a $d$-dimensional setting (here $d=3$) you have to select $d$ "independent" functions as your coordinate variables. Such a triple can be the cartesian coordinates $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$, spherical coordinates $(r,\phi,\theta)$, cylindrical coordinates $(\rho,\phi, z)$, or some other more general coordinates appropriate for your problem.

Only *after* you have selected a *complete* such triple you are allowed to talk about partial derivatives with respect to the coordinate variables appearing therein. The partial derivation operators, like
$${\partial\over \partial r},\ {\partial\over \partial \phi},\ {\partial\over \partial \theta}$$
form the dual basis (in the sense of linear algebra) of the basis formed by the coordinate differentials $dr$, $d\phi$, $d\theta$, and are inherently linked to all three of them.

It follows that given some two functions $f,\ g:\ \Bbb R^3\to \Bbb R$ it makes absolutely no sense to talk about a standalone derivative ${\displaystyle{\partial f\over\partial g}}$. In fact the quotient of the infinitesimal changes in $f$ and $g$ under a small displacement starting at a point $p$ depends heavily on the direction of this displacement.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Let's say I choose $(x_1, x_2,x_3)$ and I chose 1 specific direction $x_1$. Is it then that the result will be $n_{1,21}/n_{2,31}$

Comment: @noob: As you indicate, the quotient $n_{1,21}/n_{2,31}$ has a definite meaning. It describes the ratio of the infinitesimal changes of the quantities $n_{1,2}$ and $n_{2,3}$ under a displacement in the $x_1$-direction.